# Add text below AJAX loading icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm using jQuery to show http://ajaxload.info/ icon.

```
$(".modal").show();
```

```html
<div class="modal"></div>
```

```css
.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8 ) url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhHRx.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat;
}
```

I want to add some text below the icon. I've tried having new div inside class="modal" div but it doesn't work because what I need is to add the text on the background.
How can I had text below the background image?

Comment: Where and how are you showing the icon?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the icon is being displayed with the CSS `background` property.

Comment: The icon is displayed using the background property. just like @Mark_M said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it were me, I wouldn't use the `background` image. I would do something like this:

```
<style>
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    text-align:center;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba( 255,255,255, .8 ) 
}
.modal::before {
    margin: auto;
    display:block ;
    text-align: center;
    content: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhHRx.gif');
}
</style>
<div class="modal"><p>Content loading</p></div>
```

Here' a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hsyprw2m/2/

Comment: It works! thanks @Mark_M. I'm now fighting to put it in the middle of the screen again :)

Comment: You should be able to do something like this with `top`: https://jsfiddle.net/hsyprw2m/5/